# Magento Configurable Product Error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, configurable-product

Random occurrence - can't emulate on command but it happens every few minutes it seems. Adding configurable products (that only have one option usually for size) - once its added to the cart there is an error showing up in the cart saying : "selected option(s) or their combination is not currently available"

I could remove said products - re-add and the error wouldn't show. This is happening FAR too often to be a inconvenience.

Any clues?

Magento Community 1.8.1.0

Comment: What is the frequency that you update stock.

Comment: The inventory settings are 'off' because they don't manage stock at all. Configurables are setup just to allow size/colour choices.

Comment: How are you adding products?

Comment: Adding via the backend admin panel as either new product or via configurable 'quick add'